# trying to use a mongoose schema in another schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a User model that has a property for currentGroup:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
email: String,
currentGroup: {
  id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Session"
  }
},
password: String
});
```

The current group is supposed to be a Session, which is another MongoDB collection I have defined.

In one of my routes I am trying to set the currentGroup of a user to a specific session:

```
Session.findById(req.params.id, function(err, session){
  if(!err){
    . . .
    req.user.currentGroup = session;
    . . .
  }
});
```

However this doesn't do anything and the value of currentGroup of the user is always null even though the session variable contains actual values and is not null.

How do you use a document in a specific collection as a property of another document?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include a collection inside another like you did, you should use **populate()** which is similar to joins in SQL.

Take a look at [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)